# what's the statement execution order of this JS closure ？

Tags: javascript, closures

I have known the key of closure is about scope. But I don't know the specific execution order of it.

A classical code from 《Professional JavaScript for Web Developers 3rd Edition》about closures.

```js
function createFunctions(){
 var result=new Array();
 alert('haha');
 for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
  result[i]=function(){
   alert(i);
   return i;
  };
 }
 return result;
}
var a=createFunctions();
```

To my surprise, 'haha' was alerted while none of 'i' were alerted.I was just assigning the function to variable a.Why the statement "alert('haha')" was alerted while the cycle wasn' t executed?

when I add the below code,

```js
 var a=createFunctions();
    alert(a[2]);
```

```
why it alerted like this
```

```js
function (){
       return i;
      }
```

not like

```js
function (){
          return 2;
          }
```

Furthermore when I add the below code, what will being the order of statements executed especially the statements in the cycle.

```js
    var a=createFunctions();
       alert(a[2]());
```

Comment: Why should `i`s be alerted? You're never calling those functions. Also, all the functions within the array when ever run will alert you 10...

Comment: That book is quite old. I suggest you find one that is more up-to-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
var a=createFunctions()
```

alert('haha') is executed immediately, and an array of 10 functions is created and assigned to the variable 'a', each function alerting 'i' and returning it.

However, by the time *any* of those functions is called (provided you call them after creating them) the value of i is '10' (the loop termination value). So every time you call one of the functions, with

```
alert(a[x]())
```

( with any value of x = 0 thru 9 ) 
it will alert(10) as the function executes and alert(10) again when it returns.

Comment: why the ten functions created return i not 0~9?

Answer (score 0):

> Why the statement "alert('haha')" was alerted

Because it was an alert statement in the function you called.

> while the cycle wasn' t executed

The cycle **was** executed. The cycle just creates some functions and assigns them to positions in an array. You never call any of those functions.

> and when I add the below code, what will being the order of statements executed

It depends where you add it.